# Does Microsoft LightSwitch require Silverlight on the client?

Tags: silverlight, rad, visual-studio-lightswitch

[Microsoft Lightswitch](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch) is a Rapid Application Development environment currently in beta 2.  It will be part of the Visual Studio family.  There seem to be several different ways to deploy LightSwitch applications.  I would like a web only application that clients would access on tablets, and by tablets I mean the iPad.  If LightSwitch requires Silverlight that would rule out LightSwitch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The client layer of a LightSwitch application is a Silverlight application. Thus, you need on Silverlight on the client to run a LightSwitch application.

Currently Silverlight is not available on the iPad and you will not be able to run a LightSwitch application on the iPad. Perhaps in the future the [Mono team](http://www.mono-project.com/) will make it possible given that [Monotouch](http://monotouch.net/) and [Moonlight](http://mono-project.com/Moonlight) already exists, but I wouldn't count on it.

---

Fast forward to 2013 the [LightSwitch HTML client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/htmlclient.aspx) is now available as part of Visual Studio 2012 Update 2.

Answer (score 4):

You can create HTML pages. See:
LightSwitch and HTML
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/LSHTMLAPP.aspx

Comment: Very interesting.  I certainly hope this becomes a supported option.

Answer (score 1):

The only "official" client technology for LightSwitch V1 is currently Silverlight.

I'd love to see a WPF "option" along side the ability to generate a Silverlight client, but we'll just have to wait & see.

Answer (score 0):

You can easly check it by your self... just 'temporary' turn off Silverlight ( http://geekswithblogs.net/dlussier/archive/2009/04/09/130860.aspx ) and then try to launch your web app in Browser with 'disabled' Silverlight, if it works, then Lightspeed dosn't need Silverlight..

PS: do not forget to 'enable' Silverlight later :)

Comment: I could check it myself, if I had Lightswitch installed.  But I'm not going to even try it if it doesn't meet the tablet needs.